# Calling a function from other Swift class

Tags: swift

I am trying to access a function from my Class1.swift to Class2.swift

Here's my function in Class1.swift:

```
    class ExampleFormViewController: FormViewController {
......
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
            load_data()
            self.loadForm()
        }
    func get_facility(company: Int!, territory: Int!){

    }
    }
```

And here's how I call it in my Class2.swift:

```
ExampleFormViewController().get_facility(ExampleFormViewController().val_company[row], territory: ExampleFormViewController().val_territory[row])
```

The error I get in this line is: `Missing argument for parameter 'coder' in call`

Comment: You shouldn't need to create view controllers on the fly like that. Presumably Class2 is also a VC. What are these two VCs, and how do they relate? Where is this code in Class2 (eg. prepareForSegue?)

Comment: `public class FormPickerCell: FormValueCell, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {` It is a custom picker class and not a View Controller

Comment: So I'm guessing that `ExampleFormViewController` is the current VC, and you're displaying a custom picker. Either the picker needs a reference back to the VC to call this method, or the method could be static if it doesn't require any instance variables.

Comment: Sorry I am very new in Swift. How do I that?

Comment: I got rid of the errors, but why is my array count is 0?

Comment: Which array? Can you post more of your code, as it's hard to understand the context.

Answer (score 0):

Your `init` method for the class requires a coder parameter.You need an NSCoder to pass in, put in a variable called `theCoder` and then change your call to this:

```
ExampleFormViewController().get_facility(ExampleFormViewController(theCoder).val_company[row], territory: ExampleFormViewController(theCoder).val_territory[row])
```

Comment: How do I declare theCoder?

Comment: If you don't plan to use the coder, you probably shouldn't use the init method with a coder as a parameter,  try `    required init() {` and the first line to `super.init()` Are you not using the NSCoder for anything?

Comment: It is required by a Libary that I am using.